# Ensure a specific variable can be seen in VS2015 debugger in Release build?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++

I'm using VS2015 debugger to debug some C++ with many stack-based floats and loop counters. Debug mode is too slow to be practical so I must debug in Release mode, but the variables of interest are optimized away or stored in registers and not visible to the debugger.

Is there a trivial expression I can apply to the variables of interest such that a C++ compiler will be forced to commit them to stack memory even in a Release build, thus making them visible to the debugger, but with no other side effects?

As an example, this appears to work:

```
void make_visible_(void *);
#define MAKE_VISIBLE(x) make_visible_(&x);
```

Then, in some other source file:

```
void make_visible_(void *) {}
```

The need to declare a function elsewhere is annoying. If not declared in a separate source file, the compiler optimizes out the calls to make_visible_(). I can also imagine that a smart compiler using link-time optimization could optimize out the separate source file case as well.

Comment: Debugging optimized builds is fragile. The compiler may reorder code, or generate code that skips parts, or remove variables if their values can be calculated at compile-time, etc. Debugging is sometimes (quite often) frustrating, but it's still something that needs to be done properly from time to time. You might use "printf-debugging" (i.e. print out a trace of what's happening) to narrow down the code you really need to step through in a debugger to the bare minimum.

Comment: Thanks! I'm comfortable using the memory disassembler to work my way through optimized code, but not being able to reference variables by name makes evaluating expressions that use them very tedious.  Printf-style debugging is a useful suggestion, I gave it a go but each time I realise I need a different expression, I need to abort, modify the code, recompile and re-run to the problem area... which in my case is about 3/4 of an hour.  I might also need to ask for a new disk to store the debug output on :-)

Comment: Making a variable `volatile` would usually prevent it from being optimized away.

Comment: Thanks Igor, I tried the volatile keyword but it didn't seem to make any difference to the code. I assumed it was because the compiler could tell that no external code or hardware could know the variable's address in this context.